# Send an email button

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm developing a website using Wordpress coding in HTML, CSS, jQuery and PHP and I need to create a button with this information: Name, mail and message, and when the user clicks send with this information filled it will be send to an email, my question is how can I make the button work, I'm testing it on a live website. Also, where do I define the email where it would receive all the info.

```
    <?php

  //response generation function

  $response = "";

  //function to generate response
  function my_contact_form_generate_response($type, $message){

    global $response;

    if($type == "success") $response = "<div class='success'>{$message}</div>";
    else $response = "<div class='error'>{$message}</div>";

  }

  //response messages
  $not_human       = "Human verification incorrect.";
  $missing_content = "Please supply all information.";
  $email_invalid   = "Email Address Invalid.";
  $message_unsent  = "Message was not sent. Try Again.";
  $message_sent    = "Thanks! Your message has been sent.";

  //user posted variables
  $name = $_POST['message_name'];
  $email = $_POST['message_email'];
  $message = $_POST['message_text'];
  $human = 2;

  //php mailer variables
  $to = get_option('admin_email');
  $subject = "Someone sent a message from ".get_bloginfo('name');
  $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

  if(!$human == 0){
    if($human != 2) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $not_human); //not human!
    else {

      //validate email
      if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $email_invalid);
      else //email is valid
      {
        //validate presence of name and message
        if(empty($name) || empty($message)){
          my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);
        }
        else //ready to go!
        {
          $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
          if($sent) my_contact_form_generate_response("success", $message_sent); //message sent!
          else my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $message_unsent); //message wasn't sent
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if ($_POST['submitted']) my_contact_form_generate_response("error", $missing_content);

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <header class="entry-header">
              <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
              <?php the_content(); ?>

              <style type="text/css">
                .error{
                  padding: 5px 9px;
                  border: 1px solid red;
                  color: red;
                  border-radius: 3px;
                }

                .success{
                  padding: 5px 9px;
                  border: 1px solid green;
                  color: green;
                  border-radius: 3px;
                }

                form span{
                  color: red;
                }
              </style>

              <div id="respond">
                <?php echo $response; ?>
                <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
                  <p><label for="name">Name: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_name']); ?>"></label></p>
                  <p><label for="message_email">Email: <span>*</span> <br><input type="text" name="message_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['message_email']); ?>"></label></p>
                  <p><label for="message_text">Message: <span>*</span> <br><textarea type="text" name="message_text"><?php echo esc_textarea($_POST['message_text']); ?></textarea></label></p>
                  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                  <p><input type="submit"></p>
                </form>
              </div>


            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

          </article><!-- #post -->

      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
  </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: PHPMailer would probably help quite a bit. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Will it be sending to the same email address? or would the email address be different every time depending on the user?

Comment: to the same email address

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Matthew Goheen; PHPMailer will help a lot.
You'll want a html form which has a button:

```
<form action="phpmailingscript.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="information"></input>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

this form will POST the form data to phpmailingscript.php. 
To access this information from the php script:

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['information']){
    $information = $_POST['information'];
}
```

you'll then need to implement phpmailer to send the email

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create a html form which can take the data that's been input by the user and submit it via POST to a PHP file. ( See Isaac Answer ).

First test the functionality of posting your data to another page and echoing out all the variables to make sure you can see them on the next page. For example, in Isaac's code, he has named the file the data will post to "phpmailingscript.php".

Once you have the data successfully posting to "phpmailingscript.php", use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
to send the mail.

Below is example code which I have written for my work use and works perfectly. Some adjustments may have to be made to accommodate with your requirements, but should give you a good starting point    $mail = new PHPMailer();

```
  $message_header = "This is the message header\n;

  $message_footer = "This is the message footer";


  // Email FILE

  $filename = "you can define an attachment name here. delete this if not needed";
  $file_to_attach = "enter/the/filepath/to/the/attachment/here";


  $message_body = "This is the body of the message";
  $message = $message_header.$message_body.$message_footer;

  //you can change this to anything
  $mail->addReplyTo("noreply@website.com");
  $mail->From          = "noreply@website.com";
  $mail->FromName      = "noreply@website.com";
  $mail->Sender        = "noreply@website.com";



  /add the email address here
  // Add a BCC recipient, copy and paste the below line for multiple recepients
  $mail->AddBCC( "johndoe@hotmail.com" );
  $mail->AddBCC( "johndoe2@gmail.com" );

  // Set email format to plain text
  $mail->IsHTML( false );                                

  $mail->Subject = "Enter the subject of the message";
  $mail->Body    = $message;

  //add the attachment from above. 
  //delete if not needed
  $mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach, $filename );      

  $mail->send();
```